# How to prevent GUI blocking?

Tags: user-interface, multithreading, timer

I have a timer that ticks every 3 seconds.
If the timer found something a messagebox will show.
Then the timer should wait 30 seconds, before he show again the messagebox (the user of course must have time to react).

How can I handle this?

I tried a Thread.Sleep(30000), but the GUI blocks of course.

My other Idea is a second timer that will be activated after the first ticks and reactivate the first timer in the tick-method.

So: t1 tick -> msg box -> after click -> t2 enable (30 sec tick) -> t2 tick, enable t1

But I think thats not a good idea, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the Language.

In any case you have to create a second Thread that does the waiting and checking.

In case of .NET you might want to look into the "BackgroundWorker"

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)